# implement gridview in activity android studio

Tags: android, android-gridview

Is it possible to implement **gridView** in an activity file and not an xml file because I want to create the number of grids dynamically.

```
GridView grid = new GridView();
```

doesn't work. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; you were close, you just needed to pass in a context object:

```
GridView mGrid = new GridView(mContext);
```

option 1:

```
GridView mGrid = new GridView(this);
```

option 2:

```
GridView mGrid = new GridView(getContext());
```

and to set the columns dynamically, you pass in the number of columns to the gridview object you just created:

```
mGrid.setColumnWidth(numberOfColumns); //3, 4, 5, etc.
```

Here are two links from Android:

- GridView [Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)
- GridView [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html).

Comment: doesn't work error in mContext 
what is context in this case

Comment: replace 'mContext' with 'this' and let me know if it is working.

Comment: sorry it doesn't work too, what i want to do is loop with number of grids in activity as i will retrieve data and add relative data in grid
like Div in html 
if you have any other suggestions i'm lestining 
thanks in advance

Comment: if that isn't working, try GridView grid = new GridView(getContext());

Comment: cool getContext() removes the error
how can i add elements in it like a button or textview
if you have a resource of videos for it it will be great
sorry for being busy with me , thanks for your effort and sorry for my bad english

Comment: you will need an adapter to add your video resources into the gridview. here's a link to get you started: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/grid_view_custom_adapter.html and when you need to set the adapter, here's another link: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/grid_view_set_adapter.html